# pycparser retrieving function call hierarchy

Tags: function, callstack, pycparser, call-hierarchy

is there a way to get the function call stack with pycparser ?

for example if i have code like this:

```
static int Func_1(int *val)
{
    unsigned int data_1 = 0;
    int result;

    result = Func_2(val,
                    data_1
                   );

    result = Func_3(val,
                    result
                   );                 

    return result;
}
```

so with FuncDefVisitor i can retrieve **Func_1** and with FuncCallVisitor i could retrieve **Func_2** and **Func_3**

but how can i retrieve the information that e.g. **Func_2** is called from within **Func_1**  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a visitor that finds `FuncDef` nodes and runs another visitor on them that finds all `FuncCall` nodes. For example:

```
class FuncDefVisitor(c_ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_FuncDef(self, node):
        # Here node is a FuncDef node for the function definition.
        v = FuncCallVisitor()
        v.visit(node)

class FuncCallVisitor(c_ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_FuncCall(self, node):
        # do something
```

In `visit_FuncDef`, we create a new call visitor and run it on `node`, which means it only runs within the AST node for the function definition. It will find `Func_2` and `Func_3` in your code, but not func calls in other functions.

---

That said, note that you will only get the *static* call graph from this. In C functions can call others via function pointers and that's not something you can know statically in the general case.

Comment: Thanks i just tried it and it works like you described :)